# How much space on disk does a nvarchar column occupy if the string inside are shorter than the maximum length

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how much space will take in the hard disk a `nvarchar(N)` column for each record. Will it take 2 x N bytes (each character takes two bytes) or will it take different number of bytes depending on the data inside each record?

For example, I can have a table with just one column of type `nvarchar(100)` which contains numbers like these:

```
 0000000000
 0000000001
 .....
 9999999999
```

I have 10 billions (10^10) records with ten characters each of them. How much space would it take in the hard disk? 20Gb? 200Gb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all values are exactly 10 characters long, the space they will take up is:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-------+
|     Type     | Bytes per row |    Total bytes    |  GB   |
+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-------+
| NVARCHAR(10) |            22 |  220,000,000,000  |  220  |
| VARCHAR(10)  |            12 |  120,000,000,000  |  120  |
| NCHAR(10)    |            20 |  200,000,000,000  |  200  |
| CHAR(10)     |            10 |  100,000,000,000  |  100  |
+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-------+
```

[NVARCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) = 2 + (Data_Length * 2)

[VARCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) = 2 + Data_Length

[NCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql) = 2 * Column_Defined_Length

[CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) = Column_Defined_Length

Comment: This assumes `DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE` (the default) but one can specify `ROW` or `PAGE` with `CREATE/ALTER TABLE` to reduce physical space requirements. The amount of storage with compression on depends on the data. Compression can be used in all SQL Editions in SQL 2016 SP1+ but requires Enterprise in earlier versions.

Answer (score 6):

A `nvarchar(n)` column uses **(2 * actual length) + 2 bytes** of storage - always **2 bytes per character**, no matter what is stored.

So if you store 10 digits in a `nvarchar(100)` column, you're using `2*10+2 = 22 bytes` for each string.

But if you're storing only number - why are you even bothering with `nvarchar`?? Numbers should be stored in numeric columns... or if you can't, then at least use `varchar` which would **half** the storage requirements (1 character/digit = 1 byte)